# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on self.tableView.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can't run my built app because I have:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on `self.tableView.reloadData()`.

I connected to API using Alamofire and SwiftyJson, and also connected tableView outlet.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var coinData: [CoinModel]  = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchCoinData()
    }

    func fetchCoinData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Alamofire.request("https://api.coincap.io/v2/markets").responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case.success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let data = json["data"]
                    data.array?.forEach({ (user) in
                        let user = CoinModel(coin: user["baseSymbol"].stringValue,coinName: user["baseId"].stringValue, coinPrice: user["priceUsd"].stringValue)
                        self.coinData.append(user)
                        print(user.coin)
                        print(user.coinPrice)
                        print(user.coinName)
                        //print(data)
                    })

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                case.failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.coinData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "CoinTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CoinTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of CoinTableViewCell.")
        }

        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        let coin = coinData[indexPath.row]

        cell.coinLabel.text = coin.coin
        cell.coinNameLabel.text = coin.coinName
        cell.coinPriceLabel.text = coin.coinPrice
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Comment: do not call api on main thread, you need use main thread to update UI

Comment: could you explain how?

Comment: it ain't the issue the OP is facing @Hitesh

Comment: this way you can use 
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in 
   self?.tableView.reloadData()
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your given code

```
let user = CoinModel(coin: user["baseSymbol"].stringValue,coinName: user["baseId"].stringValue, coinPrice: user["priceUsd"].stringValue)
```

this line seems to be the culprit, here possible taking of stringValue of nil causing this force unwrapping crash.

I would rather use optional unwrapping

```
if let baseSymbol = user["baseSymbol"] as? String,
    // other two goes underneath
   {
    // prepare the user using those unwrapped values

  }
```

Comment: how to resolve this line?

Comment: please check the updated answer

Comment: But the question states the error is on the line `self.tableView.reloadData()` so how does this answer apply?